# customization of iphone key panel in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, xcode4, xcode4.2

I am developing a iphone app in different language and now i have to change the key panel layout.

Image is given below

[image: Layout]

I want to change the return button text in different language . This can be possible? If it is, then give me some advice for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language of the keyboard is the user's choice. If he's from Germany he probably set the OS and the keyboard to German too. Try going to the Settings app and change the keyboard.